# Using remove as opposite of append not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's how I append the value:

```
$('<div>someText</div>').appendTo(self);
```

And here's how I want to remove it:

```
$(self).remove('<div>someText</div>');
```

The appending works, the removing doesnt. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.remove()` function takes a selector to filter the already matched elements, not to match elements *inside* of them. What you want is something like this:

```
$(self).find('div:contains(someText)').remove();
```

That will find a `<div>` element containing the text `someText` inside of whatever element `self` is, then removes it.

Answer (score 1):

The API http://api.jquery.com/remove/ sais that a selector is required.

<strike>Try `$(self).remove('> div');`
This will remove the first childs of div.</strike>

You can use `$(self).filter('div:contains("someText")').remove();` to remove a div with a specific content or `$(self).find('> div').remove();` to remove the first childs of div.

EDIT: removed first version I posted without testing.

Comment: From the documentation: "A selector expression that **filters the set of matched elements** to be removed." I'm pretty sure it doesn't search inside of the elements, it just filters down the ones that are already inside the jQuery object. It's also not required, since the parameter is optional (denoted by the square brackets in the doc).

Answer (score 0):

It most likely has to do with the scope of self. Since you've named it self I am assuming that you are getting this variable using $(this) on the click event. If that's the case, and you want to call the remove method, you can only do so from within the same function. Otherwise you need to either store the element in a variable or provide another selector to access it.

```
Example:

<div class="div1"></div>
```

this will be the div with the click event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var self = null;
    $('.div1').click(function(e){
         self = $(this);
         var itemToAdd = '<div>SomeText</div>';
         $(itemToAdd).appendTo(self);
    });
    // to remove it
    // this will remove the text immediately after it's placed 
    // this call needs to be wrapped in a function called on another event
    $('.div1').find('div:contains(someText)').remove();      
});
```